# How to include fieldset element w/ Responsive Table "flipscroll" (and not break layout)?

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-table, media-queries, fieldset

When using a "fieldset" wrapper around my responsive "flipscroll" table, it will break the layout.. but when "fieldset" is not applied as a wrapper the style is correct. The reason I need to use fieldset is to have the check all checkboxes function.

Resize the screen from "Screen" mode to "Mobile" mode to see the issue. "Mobile" mode is where the problem exists.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MJ2nt/

**HTML**

```
    <h1>Problem with "Fieldset" and "Responsive" table</h1>
    <p>Responsive table works fine without "fieldset" element as a wrapper, but breaks when "fieldset" is wrapped around the table. The reason to use "fieldset" element in this case is for the "checkall" class that will check all checkboxes on/off. Does anyone have any idea what may be wrong?

    <h2>Flip Scroll (Responsive Table)</h1>
    <p>Works fine without "fieldset" element</p>

    <table class="flipscroll clear">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="center checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkall" class="checkall" />
                    </label>
                </th>

                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
                <th>Column 4</th>
                <th>Column 5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>            

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Mario Rossi</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_unread">512k</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Jackie Angelica</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_pp">256k</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Penelope Stevens</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_word">128k</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Maria Gupta</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_text">64k</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Adeline Danica</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_excel">32k</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Johan Celestine</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_read">16k</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>







    <h2 class="error">Flip Scroll (Responsive Table w/ Fieldset)</h1>
    <p class="error">Breaks table when "fieldset" element is added around table</p>

    <fieldset>
    <table class="flipscroll clear">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="center checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkall" class="checkall" />
                    </label>
                </th>

                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
                <th>Column 4</th>
                <th>Column 5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>            

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Mario Rossi</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_unread">512k</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Jackie Angelica</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_pp">256k</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Penelope Stevens</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_word">128k</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Maria Gupta</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_text">64k</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Adeline Danica</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_excel">32k</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="select"/></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">Johan Celestine</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a></td>
                <td class="ellipsis">12/12/2013</td>
                <td class="ellipsis"><span class="attachment icon_read">16k</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="mobile tablet screen"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    /* 
    ==========================================================================
        SCREEN MODE
    ========================================================================== */
    body { background: #BFEEFC; padding: 1em 1em 5em; }
    h1 { margin: 1em 0 0; }
    h2 { margin: 1em 0 0; }
    p { margin: .25em 0 1em; }
    fieldset { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }

    table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; background: white; }
    table thead { background: #f2f2f2; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
    table thead tr {  }
    table thead tr th { text-align: left; }

    .flipscroll { width: 100%; }
    .flipscroll tbody { overflow-y: hidden; }

    /* Screen Style */
    @media screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
        .screen { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0;padding: .5em 1em; background: black; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.7em; display: block; }
        .screen:after { content: "Screen"; }
    }

    /* 
    ==========================================================================
        MOBILE MODE
    ========================================================================== */
    @media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 64em) {
        .mobile { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0;padding: .5em 1em; background: black; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.7em; display: block; }
        .mobile:after { content: "Mobile"; }

        /* Flip Scroll */
        .featurecards .flipscroll { border-top: 0 !important; }

        .flipscroll * { border: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; position: relative; }
        .flipscroll { background: #f2f2f2; border-left: 1px solid #cccccc !important; display: block; position: relative; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-spacing: 0 !important; border-top: 1px solid #cccccc !important; }
        .flipscroll br { display: none; }
        .flipscroll thead { display: block; float: left; width: 35%; min-width: 10em; }
        .flipscroll thead tr { display: block; padding: 0 !important; }
        .flipscroll thead tr th { text-align: left; display: block; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap; text-align: left; padding: .5em 1em !important; width: 100% !important; min-width: 100% !important; }
        .flipscroll thead tr th div div { padding: .3em .5em; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; box-sizing: border-box; }
        .flipscroll tbody { background: white; display: block; width: auto; position: relative; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap; border-left: 1px solid #cccccc !important; }
        .flipscroll tbody tr { display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid #cccccc !important; }
        .flipscroll tbody tr td { display: block; text-align: left !important; padding: .5em 1em !important; font-size: 1em !important; }
        .flipscroll tbody tr td:after { content: "\00a0"; }
        .flipscroll tbody tr td input[type="button"] { padding: .5em 1em !important; float: left !important; margin: 0 .5em 0 0; min-width: 7em; }

        .error { color: red; }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with:

**CSS**

```
    fieldset { min-width: min-content; }
```

For some reason it automatically defaults to min-width: min-content when the "Flipscroll" technique is applied.

**CSS SOLUTION**

```
    fieldset { min-width: 100%; }
```

Just add min-width: 100% and everything should fall back into place.